# Delete row from sql DB php

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

I have a problem with my code because I can't delete a record from the database.

Everything seems ok, it displays the info about deleting but it stays in the database. Here is the code:

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:Elections.db');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if ( isset($_POST['confirm']) && $_POST['confirm'] == 'yes'){
        try{


            $sql= "DELETE FROM Elections WHERE id=:ELectionId";

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            $ElectionId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ElectionId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(':ElectionId', $ElectionId, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $stmt->execute();
            $ppdo = null;

            $ElectionId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ElectionId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(':ElectionId', $ElectionId, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $stmt->execute();
            $ppdo = null;
            echo '<h1>Event removed</h1>';
            echo '<a href="AdminElections.php">Return to Admin menu</a>';

        } catch (PDOException $e ){
            print "We had an error: " . $e->getMessage(). "<br/>";
            die();
        }
    } else {
        echo 'You need confirm.';

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo:

```
$sql= "DELETE FROM Elections WHERE id=:ELectionId";
```

Should be ("l" lowercase"):

```
$sql= "DELETE FROM Elections WHERE id=:ElectionId";
```

EDIT:

Valuable comment from @Mike

This is why you should always either set an error mode like `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` (which is most sensible) or manually inspect the `PDO::errorCode()` and `PDO::errorInfo()` methods after each query.

Comment: This is why you should always either set an error mode like `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` (which is most sensible) or manually inspect the `PDO::errorCode()` and `PDO::errorInfo()` methods after each query.

Comment: Oh my God thank you so much I am so tired that I couldn't notice that